# How to Get Class Name of an Object?

Tags: magento-1.7

Is there a quick way to check the name of an object. For example, if I do...

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->...;
```

How can I get check to see it is a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` for `$product`?

Comment: How about instanceof http://php.net/instanceof ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo get_class($product);
```

Will return the class name. [Here I have demonstrated it in the boris console for the Magento command line](https://gist.github.com/Vinai/5579309):

```
[4] boris> get_class($product);
 → string(26) "Mage_Catalog_Model_Product"
```

You can also get things like defined methods on the class itself:

```
var_dump(get_class_methods($product));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to determine if the actual class instantiated is a specific class, then `get_class` is what you are looking for. However, if you are only trying to determine if you have a valid product object, use the `instanceof` operator which will evaluate true if it is either the class you're checking against or an instance of a descending class. A rewritten product model would invalidate a check for a product object were `get_class` used vs `instanceof` which would still pass assuming the rewrite class extended the core product class.

Comment: This is great insight - the actual usage is the important key here, not just the method by which to obtain the class name.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this. I was actually using `instanceof`, and it does what you say. Works great for classes that extend Mage classes.